# Remove duplicates from a string array using excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following VBA code in Excel 2010 that reads the numbers in column A into a comma separated string.
The numbers are sorted in column A

However, I was wondering if there was a way to either remove the duplicate numbers while reading them to to the comma separated variable, or a way to remove all the duplicates from the variable after it has been built.

Here is my code that builds the comma separated list

```
Dim LR As Long

    Dim RangeOutput
    Dim entry As Variant
    Dim FinalResult As String
    
    LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        On Error Resume Next    'if only 1 row
    
    For Each entry In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & LR)
        If Not IsEmpty(entry.Value) Then
            RangeOutput = RangeOutput & entry.Value & ","
        End If
    Next

    FinalResult = Left(RangeOutput, Len(RangeOutput) - 1)
```

Comment: Use a `Scripting.Dictionary` to keep track of the unique numbers. Or if your version of Excel supports it, `WorksheetFunction.Unique`.

Comment: I'm quite new to VBA and do not yet have the skill set to add the Scripting.Dictionary code to the above to obtain unique numbers. I have tried and end up with either the last or all the duplicates. I think I'll just resort to copying them to another sheet, as I know that works.

Comment: Do you must need `VBA`? If you show some sample data then you may get answer also by excel formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do it with a dictionary.

```
Dim arrData As Variant
Dim dic As Object
Dim idx As Long
    
    arrData = Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Columns(1).Value
    
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    For idx = 2 To UBound(arrData, 1)
        If arrData(idx, 1) <> "" Then
            dic(arrData(idx, 1)) = ""
        End If
    Next idx

    FinalResult = Join(dic.keys, ",")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Collection to achieve same result:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    '
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Missing required worksheet", vbExclamation, "Cancelled"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    '
    Dim lastRowIndex As Long
    '
    lastRowIndex = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Notice the range is fully referenced with the sheet
    If lastRowIndex = 1 Then
        MsgBox "No data found in column A", vbInformation, "Cancelled"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    '
    Dim arrValues As Variant
    '
    arrValues = ws.Range("A2:A" & lastRowIndex).Value2
    If Not IsArray(arrValues) Then arrValues = Array(arrValues) 'Just in case lastRow is 2
    '
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim uniqueValues As New Collection
    '
    On Error Resume Next 'For duplicated values - collections do not allow duplicated keys
    For Each v In arrValues
        uniqueValues.Add v, CStr(v)
    Next v
    On Error GoTo 0
    '
    Dim arrResult() As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim result As String
    '
    ReDim arrResult(0 To uniqueValues.Count - 1)
    i = 0
    For Each v In uniqueValues
        arrResult(i) = CStr(v) 'In case there are errors like #N/A
        i = i + 1
    Next v
    '
    result = Join(arrResult, ",")
    Debug.Print result
End Sub
```